# Format Two Rows into One Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to combine two row results into one single row. Here are my results:

```
| OwnerTaxRate | OwnerTaxAmount | OwnerTaxTotal | LoanTaxRate | LoanTaxAmount | LoanTaxTotal
|     8.4%     |     71.40      |     921.4     |    NULL     |     NULL      |    NULL
|     NULL     |     NULL       |     NULL      |    8.4%     |     10.08     |    130.08
```

Here are how I need the results to return.

```
| OwnerTaxRate | OwnerTaxAmount | OwnerTaxTotal | LoanTaxRate | LoanTaxAmount | LoanTaxTotal
|     8.4%     |     71.40      |     921.4     |    8.4%     |     10.08     |    130.08
```

The reason it is creating two rows is because there are two entries for each order based on the `LoanHolder` (it is either 0 or 1). I thought adding a `CASE` statement to select which LoanHolder I wanted to pull for would work, but evidently not. Here is my `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN
            ORC.LoanHolder = 1 
            THEN  CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),ORC.Owner_TaxRateBasic) + '%'
        ELSE NULL END AS 'OwnerTaxRate'
    ,CASE 
        WHEN
            ORC.LoanHolder = 1 
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxAmountBasic > 0 
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxAmountSimultaneous = 0 
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxAmountAssociated = 0 
            THEN ORC.Owner_TaxAmountBasic
        WHEN
            ORC.LoanHolder = 1
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxAmountBasic = 0 
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxAmountSimultaneous > 0 
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxAmountAssociated = 0 
            THEN ORC.Owner_TaxAmountSimultaneous
        WHEN
            ORC.LoanHolder = 1
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxAmountBasic = 0 
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxAmountSimultaneous = 0 
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxAmountAssociated > 0 
            THEN ORC.Owner_TaxAmountAssociated
        ELSE NULL END AS 'OwnerTaxAmount'
    ,CASE 
        WHEN
            ORC.LoanHolder = 1
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxTotalBasic > 0 
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxTotalSimultaneous = 0 
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxTotalAssociated = 0 
            THEN ORC.Owner_TaxTotalBasic
        WHEN
            ORC.LoanHolder = 1
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxTotalBasic = 0 
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxTotalSimultaneous > 0 
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxTotalAssociated = 0 
            THEN ORC.Owner_TaxTotalSimultaneous
        WHEN
            ORC.LoanHolder = 1
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxTotalBasic = 0 
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxTotalSimultaneous = 0 
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxTotalAssociated > 0 
            THEN ORC.Owner_TaxTotalAssociated
        ELSE NULL END AS 'OwnerTaxTotal'
    ,CASE 
        WHEN
            ORC.LoanHolder = 0 
            THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),ORC.Loan_TaxRateBasic) + '%'
        ELSE NULL END AS 'LoanTaxRate'
    ,CASE 
        WHEN
            ORC.LoanHolder = 0
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxAmountBasic > 0 
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxAmountSimultaneous = 0 
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxAmountAssociated = 0 
            THEN ORC.Loan_TaxAmountBasic
        WHEN
            ORC.LoanHolder = 0
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxAmountBasic = 0 
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxAmountSimultaneous > 0 
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxAmountAssociated = 0 
            THEN ORC.Loan_TaxAmountSimultaneous
        WHEN
            ORC.LoanHolder = 0
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxAmountBasic = 0 
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxAmountSimultaneous = 0 
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxAmountAssociated > 0 
            THEN ORC.Loan_TaxAmountAssociated
        ELSE NULL END AS 'LoanTaxAmount'
    ,CASE 
        WHEN
            ORC.LoanHolder = 0
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxTotalBasic > 0 
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxTotalSimultaneous = 0 
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxTotalAssociated = 0 
            THEN ORC.Loan_TaxTotalBasic
        WHEN
            ORC.LoanHolder = 0
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxTotalBasic = 0 
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxTotalSimultaneous > 0 
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxTotalAssociated = 0 
            THEN ORC.Loan_TaxTotalSimultaneous
        WHEN
            ORC.LoanHolder = 0
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxTotalBasic = 0 
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxTotalSimultaneous = 0 
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxTotalAssociated > 0 
            THEN ORC.Loan_TaxTotalAssociated
        ELSE NULL END AS 'LoanTaxTotal'
FROM
    OrderRateCalculation ORC
WHERE
    ORC.OrdersID = @OrdersID
```

Comment: You show two rows but only one query. If you are using two querys you could use a UNION, but i don't know if thats the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE 
        WHEN
            ORC.LoanHolder = 1 
            THEN  CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),ORC.Owner_TaxRateBasic) + '%'
        ELSE NULL END) AS 'OwnerTaxRate'
    ,MAX(CASE 
        WHEN
            ORC.LoanHolder = 1 
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxAmountBasic > 0 
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxAmountSimultaneous = 0 
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxAmountAssociated = 0 
            THEN ORC.Owner_TaxAmountBasic
        WHEN
            ORC.LoanHolder = 1
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxAmountBasic = 0 
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxAmountSimultaneous > 0 
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxAmountAssociated = 0 
            THEN ORC.Owner_TaxAmountSimultaneous
        WHEN
            ORC.LoanHolder = 1
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxAmountBasic = 0 
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxAmountSimultaneous = 0 
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxAmountAssociated > 0 
            THEN ORC.Owner_TaxAmountAssociated
        ELSE NULL END) AS 'OwnerTaxAmount'
    ,MAX(CASE 
        WHEN
            ORC.LoanHolder = 1
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxTotalBasic > 0 
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxTotalSimultaneous = 0 
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxTotalAssociated = 0 
            THEN ORC.Owner_TaxTotalBasic
        WHEN
            ORC.LoanHolder = 1
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxTotalBasic = 0 
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxTotalSimultaneous > 0 
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxTotalAssociated = 0 
            THEN ORC.Owner_TaxTotalSimultaneous
        WHEN
            ORC.LoanHolder = 1
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxTotalBasic = 0 
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxTotalSimultaneous = 0 
            AND ORC.Owner_TaxTotalAssociated > 0 
            THEN ORC.Owner_TaxTotalAssociated
        ELSE NULL END) AS 'OwnerTaxTotal'
    ,MAX(CASE 
        WHEN
            ORC.LoanHolder = 0 
            THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),ORC.Loan_TaxRateBasic) + '%'
        ELSE NULL END) AS 'LoanTaxRate'
    ,MAX(CASE 
        WHEN
            ORC.LoanHolder = 0
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxAmountBasic > 0 
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxAmountSimultaneous = 0 
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxAmountAssociated = 0 
            THEN ORC.Loan_TaxAmountBasic
        WHEN
            ORC.LoanHolder = 0
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxAmountBasic = 0 
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxAmountSimultaneous > 0 
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxAmountAssociated = 0 
            THEN ORC.Loan_TaxAmountSimultaneous
        WHEN
            ORC.LoanHolder = 0
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxAmountBasic = 0 
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxAmountSimultaneous = 0 
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxAmountAssociated > 0 
            THEN ORC.Loan_TaxAmountAssociated
        ELSE NULL END) AS 'LoanTaxAmount'
    ,MAX(CASE 
        WHEN
            ORC.LoanHolder = 0
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxTotalBasic > 0 
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxTotalSimultaneous = 0 
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxTotalAssociated = 0 
            THEN ORC.Loan_TaxTotalBasic
        WHEN
            ORC.LoanHolder = 0
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxTotalBasic = 0 
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxTotalSimultaneous > 0 
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxTotalAssociated = 0 
            THEN ORC.Loan_TaxTotalSimultaneous
        WHEN
            ORC.LoanHolder = 0
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxTotalBasic = 0 
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxTotalSimultaneous = 0 
            AND ORC.Loan_TaxTotalAssociated > 0 
            THEN ORC.Loan_TaxTotalAssociated
        ELSE NULL END) AS 'LoanTaxTotal'
FROM
    OrderRateCalculation ORC
WHERE
    ORC.OrdersID = @OrdersID
```

Comment: Bingo! That returns the results as needed. Thanks much for the prompt assistance in my moment of idiocy!

Answer (score 0):

Join the table with another instance of itself based on your loanHolder

```
    SELECT
        (CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),ORC1.Owner_TaxRateBasic) + '%') AS 'OwnerTaxRate'
        ,CASE 
            WHEN
                ORC1.Owner_TaxAmountBasic > 0 
                AND ORC1.Owner_TaxAmountSimultaneous = 0 
                AND ORC1.Owner_TaxAmountAssociated = 0 
                THEN ORC1.Owner_TaxAmountBasic
            WHEN
                ORC1.Owner_TaxAmountBasic = 0 
                AND ORC1.Owner_TaxAmountSimultaneous > 0 
                AND ORC1.Owner_TaxAmountAssociated = 0 
                THEN ORC1.Owner_TaxAmountSimultaneous
            WHEN
                ORC1.Owner_TaxAmountBasic = 0 
                AND ORC1.Owner_TaxAmountSimultaneous = 0 
                AND ORC1.Owner_TaxAmountAssociated > 0 
                THEN ORC1.Owner_TaxAmountAssociated
            ELSE NULL END AS 'OwnerTaxAmount'
        ,CASE 
            WHEN
                ORC1.Owner_TaxTotalBasic > 0 
                AND ORC1.Owner_TaxTotalSimultaneous = 0 
                AND ORC1.Owner_TaxTotalAssociated = 0 
                THEN ORC1.Owner_TaxTotalBasic
            WHEN
                ORC1.Owner_TaxTotalBasic = 0 
                AND ORC1.Owner_TaxTotalSimultaneous > 0 
                AND ORC1.Owner_TaxTotalAssociated = 0 
                THEN ORC1.Owner_TaxTotalSimultaneous
            WHEN
                ORC1.Owner_TaxTotalBasic = 0 
                AND ORC1.Owner_TaxTotalSimultaneous = 0 
                AND ORC1.Owner_TaxTotalAssociated > 0 
                THEN ORC1.Owner_TaxTotalAssociated
            ELSE NULL END AS 'OwnerTaxTotal'
        ,(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),ORC0.Loan_TaxRateBasic) + '%') AS 'LoanTaxRate'
        ,CASE 
            WHEN
                ORC0.Loan_TaxAmountBasic > 0 
                AND ORC0.Loan_TaxAmountSimultaneous = 0 
                AND ORC0.Loan_TaxAmountAssociated = 0 
                THEN ORC0.Loan_TaxAmountBasic
            WHEN
                ORC0.Loan_TaxAmountBasic = 0 
                AND ORC0.Loan_TaxAmountSimultaneous > 0 
                AND ORC0.Loan_TaxAmountAssociated = 0 
                THEN ORC0.Loan_TaxAmountSimultaneous
            WHEN
                ORC0.Loan_TaxAmountBasic = 0 
                AND ORC0.Loan_TaxAmountSimultaneous = 0 
                AND ORC0.Loan_TaxAmountAssociated > 0 
                THEN ORC0.Loan_TaxAmountAssociated
            ELSE NULL END AS 'LoanTaxAmount'
        ,CASE 
            WHEN
                ORC0.Loan_TaxTotalBasic > 0 
                AND ORC0.Loan_TaxTotalSimultaneous = 0 
                AND ORC0.Loan_TaxTotalAssociated = 0 
                THEN ORC0.Loan_TaxTotalBasic
            WHEN
                ORC0.Loan_TaxTotalBasic = 0 
                AND ORC0.Loan_TaxTotalSimultaneous > 0 
                AND ORC0.Loan_TaxTotalAssociated = 0 
                THEN ORC0.Loan_TaxTotalSimultaneous
            WHEN
                ORC0.Loan_TaxTotalBasic = 0 
                AND ORC0.Loan_TaxTotalSimultaneous = 0 
                AND ORC0.Loan_TaxTotalAssociated > 0 
                THEN ORC0.Loan_TaxTotalAssociated
            ELSE NULL END AS 'LoanTaxTotal'
    FROM
        OrderRateCalculation ORC0
        join OrderRateCalculation ORC1 on ORC1.OrdersID = ORC0.OrdersID and ORC1.LoanHolder = 1
    WHERE
        ORC.OrdersID = @OrdersID and ORC0.LoanHolder = 0
```